# How to get rid of Impossible to process constructor argument error?

Tags: magento2.4.2-p1

When I go to compile I get this error-

```
 php bin/magento setup:di:compile

 The compilation was started.
 Area configuration aggregation... 5/9 [===============>------------]  55% 40 secs 517.0 MiB
 In ClassReader.php line 45:
                                                                                                                      
 Impossible to process constructor argument Parameter #1 [ <required> Amasty\Base\Model\FilesystemProvider $filesystemP  
rovider ] of Amasty\Base\Helper\Deploy class                                                                            
                                                                                                                      

 In ClassReader.php line 34:
                                                         
Class Amasty\Base\Model\FilesystemProvider does not exist
```

In order to start troubleshooting, I disabled all third-party extensions. I then ran-

rm -rf ./pub/static/*
rm -rf ./var/view_generated/*
rm -rf ./var/page_cache/*
rm -rf ./var/view_preprocessed/*
rm -rf generated/*
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
php bin/magento setup:di:compile

But the error will not go away. I am on Magento 2.4.2-p1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My solution was to delete the vendor folder and reinstall everything in composer. It worked and I have no idea why.

Answer (score 0):

disabling the extension even from config.php does not remove it from the list of extensions Magento compiles during di:compile, to remove it from that list comment out the registration.php file of the extension.